# Change the value of the return of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL server and want to create a stored procedure that if it matches a certain value, it changes the value of the data eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAnimals] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT DISTINCT AnimalId,AnimalName,etc from [dbo].[Animals] order by AnimalName
```

What I want is: 
If I found, for example, an animal which name is lion change it to Lion or another name?

```
if(AnimalName == 'lion'){
    AnimalName = 'Lion Abc12'
}
```

Something like that but in a stored procedure.
Can I do it with a stored procedure and how?
BTW I can't change the values directly in the DB so that's why I think about this approach, what would you do?

> I don't want to capitalize instead change it to another different
>   value

Thanks

Comment: @maSTAShuFu is not it was just an example maybe change lion to Lion ABc pls remove the duplicate tag

Comment: Are you returning these values to an application?  If so I would recommend accepting the sql output without manipulation, and then using your application code to manipulate it for your needs.  Also, be careful that you are using the data as read only.  If you manipulate it and later do an update, you will in fact change the data in the db.

Comment: `Case` statement in the `Select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would let you set up whatever values you want to adapt

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAnimals] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT DISTINCT AnimalId,
case 
    when AnimalName='Lion' and pk=1 and fk=2 then 'Lion (Extra Large)'
    when AnimalName='Lion' and pk=4 and fk=1 then 'Lioness'
    when AnimalName='Lion' then 'Default Lion'
    when AnimalName='Aardvark' then 'Aaaaardvark'
    when AnimalName='Poacher' then 'Target'
    else AnimalName end as AnimalName,
etc from [dbo].[Animals] 
order by AnimalName
```

note that SQL Server comparison is not case sensitive (unless you force it that way), so *lion*, *Lion* and *LiON* are all the same

Comment: should add depending on the server collation

Comment: I forgot to mention that the name could be duplicated, but you can distinguish them by the pk and fk, so I guess the case would be :  `case pk and fk WHERE pk =1 AND fk = 2` , can you help me with it? Thanks

Comment: changed the `case when` to show multiple parameters, and also show you how to select a default value should the other tests not work

Comment: BTW performance wise what would be faster? this approach or the one proposed by @Wendy (a temporal table), Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either use a select case, or if there are a lot of records, insert into a temp table and update as required.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetAnimals] 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT DISTINCT AnimalId,AnimalName,etc 
Into #tmpAnimal
from [dbo].[Animals] 

Update #tmpAnimal
Set AnimalName = 'LionABC'
Where AnimalName = 'Lion'

Select * from #tmpAnimal
order by AnimalName

Drop table #tmpAnimal
```